# Find and sort files by date modified

Tags: linux, find, ls

I know that there are many answers to this question online. However, I would like to know if this alternate solution would work:

```
ls -lt `find . -name "*.jpg" -print | head -10`
```

I'm aware of course that this will only give me the first 10 results. The reason I'm asking is because I'm not sure whether the `ls` is executing separately for each result of `find` or not. Thanks

Comment: There's a similar question in the Unix and Linux exchange: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29899/how-can-i-use-find-and-sort-the-results-by-mtime

Comment: I also just realized that putting `head` inside the backticks doesn't do what I actually want

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your solution:

- the `ls` will be executed after the `find` is evaluated
- it is likely that `find` will yield too many results for `ls` to process, in which case you might want to look at the `xargs` command

This should work better: (format is for MacOS)

```
  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f"%m %Sm %N" | sort -rn
```

The three parts of the command to this:

- find all files and print their path
- use `xargs` to process the (long) list of files and print out the modification unixtime, human readable time, and filename for each file
- sort the resulting list in reverse numerical order

The main trick is to add the numerical unixtime when the files were last modified to the beginning of the lines, and then sort them.

Comment: I realized a problem with my command above. Could you briefly explain your solution and how it works? Thanks

Comment: see explanation above

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, the modification time is the time that has passed since the epoch until the file was last modified, so a larger modification time means a recently modified file, correct?

Comment: it is the date+time the file was last modified.   Unixtime is time expressed in seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC)

Comment: `-f"%m %Sm %N"` is not valid.

Comment: This works find on a Mac. @Nikolai what computer / OS are you using? The above solution works on a Mac. On a different UNIX platform you may have to look at man pages for the correct time stamp format: look at `man strftime` to modify the string "%m %Sm %N"

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the stat command requires slightly different format parameters. Here is the amended command:

find . -type f -print0  | xargs -0 stat -c"%Y %y %N" | sort -rn | head -n 1

And this form will return only the pathname:

find . -type f -print0  | xargs -0 stat -c"%Y %y %n" | sort -rn | head -n 1 | awk '{print $5}'